# the object has been updated by another user since it was last fetched

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I'm added somefield so my SharePoint solution but i keep getting the error `the object has been updated by another user since it was last fetched.`

```
foreach (var field in new PageAndFieldData().Fields)
{

    var spField = web.Fields.FirstOrDefault(i => i.InternalName == field.field_name); // if dont exist = create

    if (spField == null)
    {
        var fieldXml = field.Xml;
        var newspField = web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldXml, false, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
        if (groups.Contains(field.group_name))
            newspField.Group = field.group_name;
        else
        {
            newspField.Group = field.group_name;
        }
        _Ctx.Load(newspField);
        _Ctx.ExecuteQuery(); <--- This line throws the error
    }
}
```

Can someone point out why it keeps throwing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure field schema (`fieldXml` variable in your case) does not contain `Version` attribute otherwise SharePoint considers the field is getting updated.

For example, the error will occur while creating a field using the following field schema:

```
<Field Version='1' Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Location' />
```

and will not with:

```
<Field Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Location' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a workflow associated with that list, that gets triggered and modifies the item simultaneously with your code.

If there is no workflow, then the item might be modified by other user, like it's saying. The point is, the item should not be modified (by others) in SP from the time you fetch it to the time you update it in SharePoint, otherwise SP rises "conflicting changes" error.

Comment: It should not be used by anyone except me, This code run when i install my custom SharePoint, so aka I cant see how anyone should modify or use the item

Comment: The workflow can be triggered by updating or creating an item in the list. So it might be your own code that creates this item a step before, for example. Anyways, the reason for this error normally is exactly that - the item is modified by two different callers simultaneously.